# coloring pixel matrix with selected colors in R

Tags: r, image, matrix, colors

I have a pixel matrix as follow:

```
0000 0001 0010 0100 1000 0011 0101 0110 1001 1010 1100 0111 1011 1101 1110 1111
CTR_NCOR      0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1
CTR_CTRI      0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1
NCOR_NCORI    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    1
NCORI_CTRI    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    0    1
```

I am able to create the pixel matrix using the `image()` function in R but can only use two colors.
I'm trying to apply the following "matrix of colors" to the image

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    2     2     2     0     3     3     3     4
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    2    2    0     0     2     3     0     3     3     4
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    2    0    2    0     2     0     3     3     0     3     4
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0    2    2    0    2     0     0     3     3     3     0     4
```

so that each square takes up a color using the corresponding number as.factor() to color the cells that have a 1.
using

```
image(first_matrix, col=as.factor(second_matrix),axes=F)
```

I get only black and blue squares, while what I'm trying to get is (following the numbers in the second matrix)

- gray (for 0s)
- green (for 1s)
- red (for 2s)
- blue (for 3s)
- light blue (for 4s)

any insight would be great! thanks :)

Comment: You should forget about using factors if working with matrices. That class of object does not accept the necessary attributes that allow factors to exist in the R universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this. R-indexing starts with 1 rather than 0):

```
image( x=1:4, y= 1:16, z=1+yourmat, 
      col= c("gray","green","red","blue","lightblue") )
```

[image]

```
yourmat <- 
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
3, 3, 3, 0, 4), .Dim = c(4L, 16L))
```